# Why is there a change in the privilege amounts needed for most actions?

Tags: bug, status-completed

After logging in this morning I noticed there was a major change in the requirement for certain privileges such as voting, having gone from 500 to 3000. Why was this change not announced when it removes privileges from users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[There was a mishap upstream](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236564/did-all-sites-just-graduate). All [seems to be good again](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Note that once we graduate beta (which seems to be [in preparation](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/743/when-will-cs-se-graduate/747#comment2484_747)) privileges *will* go up in rep requirements. Discussing whether this makes sense would be material for [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com).