# Congratulations! Computer Science is graduating!

Tags: discussion

It's a big day. You've been cleared for graduation by the Stack Exchange Community Team! Computer Science has already met our threshold for [graduation-worthy sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites), and today joins in the new design-independent graduation process! Reaching 'mature community' status is a big milestone, and you should be very proud.

You've already had an election to have celebrated this previously, but now you will receive the remaining benefits detailed in this process, which include:

- You will no longer see the "beta" label attached to your site's name
- You will become eligible for question migration paths with the rest of the network
- You will be able to select your own community ads

In the coming months, the site will receive a full design from one of our designers, which will be packaged with an increase in the amount of reputation needed to access each privilege. It's no secret that our backlog for site designs is long, and although you're looking at wait of several months, we wanted to [give you the things we could give](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation) you now. There are also bound to be bugs as the new process gets rolled out so if you come across anything out of place, please report it on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) using the [graduating-sites] tag.

This site has reached this point because of your generous contributions. Together, you've created a valuable resource that helps people. Congratulations on all you've accomplished.

Comment: _thx!_ graduated sites seem to have a front banner that points to recent chat activity. does that change also? (think its a nice feature.)

Comment: Woohoo!! A long time in the making. We're ready!!

Comment: Hmm. If the new requirements are the same as graduated sites, does that mean I lose access to (1) internal and site analytics, (2) trusted user operations, (3) the ability to protect questions, and (4) access to moderator tools? (1)-(3) aren't that important to me, but I don't want to lose (4). I know there was some discussion about this pertaining to newly-graduated sites, but it wasn't settled--what will the policy be?

Comment: @Rick The new requirements are indeed as such and would exactly entail as such to happen to your privilege access. That said, it's semi-moot as the privilege levels are not currently planned to be raised here in the near future.

Comment: @vzn That is... probably a thing that should change. But it is not a thing we did change and it turns out that's potentially not a trivial change. Still, looking into it - thanks for pointing it out, since that kinda went under our noses during all of our planning.

Comment: [meta-tag:bug] You forgot to turn off the “generate useless Community flags to keep beta mods busy” switch. We're still getting those “closed w/o comment” flags.

Comment: @Gilles I don't think they are always useless, but if that's a beta-only feature, you are right.

Comment: @GraceNote You are implying that we won't get a design in the near future? How sad.

Comment: @GraceNote The whole side bar on the homepage is the beta thing: stats have to go, other things have to come in. (Is that what you mean?)

Comment: Well done everyone!

Comment: @GraceNote I'm a bit disappointed (not surprised, though...) to see that [some sites](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/site-design-updates-are-live) get their *second* design before we (and others) get our first. Makes the "we have such a backlog" explanation ring a *little* hollow. I'm sure you (SE) have your reasons, just saying how it looks.

Comment: Any news? I notice that, by now, both larger but younger and smaller but older sites than us (size measured by traffic and questions per day) have gotten designs. Is there something we still need to do? (cc @GraceNote)

Comment: FWIW, I created a [logo inspiration thread](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1169/98). Maybe there will be some good ideas your designers can work with!